# Canvas - addEventListener not working simulating keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have the below `addEventListener` in one canvas game to control the keyboard events:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, true);
document.addEventListener("keypress", keyPress, true);
```

And the below jQuery code that simulate the keypress event to start the game.

```
$("#new").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the link click from doing anything.
  var ev = jQuery.Event("keypress"); // Build an event to simulate keypress.
  ev.which = 78; // Keycode for 'N' is 68
  ev.ctrlKey = false; // Control key is down.
  $(this).trigger(ev); // Fire!
});
```

If I press 'N' with my keyboard the canvas game is starting correctly, but when I click the `#new` div nothing happens.

My canvas element:

```
<canvas width="500px" height="480px" tabindex="1" id="game"></canvas>
```

Comment: jQuery `.trigger` only runs events bound using jQuery, not `addEventListener`.  All or nothing jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, What is the equivalent for addEventListiner in JQuery? Or any alternative way to simulate the keypress in javascript?

Comment: `$(document).bind('keydown',function(){...` or `$(document).keydown(function(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery .trigger only runs events bound using jQuery, not addEventListener.

You need to use

```
$(document).bind('keydown',function(){
```

or

```
$(document).keydown(function(){
```

to be able to use jQuery `trigger`.  All or nothing jQuery.

Alternatively, you could use native `dispatchEvent`, but that's complicated, messy and not jQuery.